# Java Applet doesn't work, warning/error: can't fully enable headless mode

Tags: java, applet, webcam

I can't figure this one out.
I have Java code that captures Webcam, it works awesome for what I need.
Issue comes along when I am trying to make an Applet out of it. I made applet, but it simply doesn't work. It doesn't create any visible errors, doesn't complain about libraries, basically nothing I can grub on to. The only thing I can see in Console log (Mac OS 10.5) is following message:

```
PluginProcess[10143]    Process manager already initialized -- can't fully enable headless mode.
```

I don't have any ideas on how to fix it. Please Advise. 
Thank you.

P.S: I just want to make Java Applet out of existing code so I can dump it into machine (any) and it can stream video from webcam.

Comment: Did you sign the applet?

Comment: That is a problem. I was looking, is there any GUI tool for signing?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you use netbeans (or eclipse I think) you can write a simple ant script which signs it for you.

Comment: Thank you. If you by any chance find out how to do it in Eclipse or make ant, please leave here link to tutorial.

Comment: I've never tried it but I would take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarsigner/

Comment: Actually jarsigner is a standard component of JDK - look inside JDK/bin directory. And read documentation. Unfortunately I never did it myself, so I cannot help you more ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574904#c23 says "this message is a
red herring:  You *always* see it (using Apple/Sun's Java Plugin2) whenever any
Java applet is displayed."

Comment: The point of my answer is that you haven't provided enough information to determine what the issue is.  The message about headless mode is not actually a problem.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the java console (via the java control panel)?

Comment: I did, right now don't remember what was there, but I couldn't figure out why it didn't run.

Comment: Actually just remembered, it did run, however I found following issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788507/lti-civil-capture-format-issues-with-applet